# Gives "System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.' " when i retrieving image from database

Tags: c#, sql-server

Help me retrieve an image from database to a `PictureBox`.

[image: System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.]

My code:

```
conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Members WHERE CardID = '" + textBox8.Text + "' OR EMP_ID = '" + textBox8.Text + "'", conn);

SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataSet dss = new DataSet();
daa.Fill(dss);

if (dss.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{ 
        MemoryStream mss = new MemoryStream((byte[])dss.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Photo"]);

        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(mss);
}

conn.Close();
```

Comment: I'm going to suggest that `mss` doesn't hold the bytes of a valid image.

Comment: Side note - concatenating strings like that could make your code vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should consider using a prepared statement.

Comment: Side note 2: Use a `using` statement for your connection, otherwise in case an exception occurs your connection will stay open. In general use using for your objects implementing IDisposable to properly free resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
 pictureBox1.Image = byteArrayToImage((byte[])dss.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Photo"]);
```

use below method:

```
 public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        System.Drawing.ImageConverter converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
        Image img = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(byteArrayIn);

        return img;
    }
```